# Is it a good practice to have a function within my class, that would run all the previous functions?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Quick question for which I could not find an answer for.

I have a class with many functions, that I implemented for better abstraction and testing, as oppose to have one big function.

Is it a good practice to create run function, that would just run all of my functions one by one?

I.E.

```
class Program:


   def func1(self):
        self.data = generate_data

   def func2(self):
        self.calc = self.data * 2

   def func3(self):
        self.calc = self.calc + self.some_csv

   def run(self):
        self.func1()
        self.func2()
        self.func3()
        return self.calc

if __name__ == "__main__":
    lock = Program(csv, 4, var, var2)
    lock.run()
```

Comment: Depends on your use case. Do you anticipate the behaviors of `func1()`, `func2()`, and `func3()` potentially changing in subclasses? Are they qualitatively different from each other? Do you actually _need_ to run all these functions back to back? Does it help your code's organization? In general, unless there's a particular reason to encapsulate functionality in many smaller functions (such as subclass overrides or external calls of only that part of the process), this is more a matter of "which way makes my code look cleaner".

Comment: In this PARTICULAR case, I would not use class variables at all.  Have `func1` return data, then have `fun2` take data as a parameter and return calc, then have `func3` take calc and return calc.  That gives you maximum re-use.  But it really depends on your use case.

Comment: The answer depends on how you want your API to work — nothing can be said generally. If running several of them in row is a common operation, then I would add it as a convenience function.

Comment: given `Program(csv, 4, var, var2)` I'm guessing the class is to give the functions access to common data stored in the instance fields which got omitted in the simplification for the question. In cases where you are asking "is this good practice" giving details about your rational like that would be helpful / relevant.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative structure.  Of course, in this specific case, there would be little point in making func1 and func2 be members of the class.  They could be standalone functions.

```
class Program:

   def func1(self, data):
        return data

   def func2(self, data):
        return data * 2

   def func3(self, calc):
        return calc + self.some_csv

   def run(self):
        data = self.func1(generate_data())
        calc = self.func2(data)
        calc = self.func3(calc)
        return calc

if __name__ == "__main__":
    lock = Program(csv, 4, var, var2)
    lock.run()
```